# How to disable "reject call with an SMS"?

Tags: calls, quick-responses

ICS introduced an option to reject incoming calls with an SMS.

Is there a way to disable this function. If yes, how?

Sony Xperia S handset running JB

Comment: Seems that there is no answer :(

Comment: So you basically want this option to not show up on the lockscreen when someone calls?

Comment: @ce4 Yep. (It's NOT on the lock screen though. It's on the bottom of the screen when someone calls me.)

Comment: I don't see that you can. It looks like, at best, you can change the possible responses to be empty fields. (Custom ROM solutions notwithstanding.)

Comment: @Al Everett Well, it kindda solves the problem. But a message still gets sent. So the base problem remains as is. :(

Comment: @Sid you can't disable it on default stock answer app but you can disable with a third party app like [HD caller ID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tw.nicky.HDCallerID&hl=en).

Comment: @avirk Oh no!! So will there be an option to this in a future software update? Using a third party app call functions is not a good option for me. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @Sid it depends on feedback of user to their phone company. If most people find it annoying then may be they will or Google but not sure if any future update will do that.

Comment: @avirk There are threads on their customer support forums, but they seem to just ignore them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to disable that. Sony is using a proprietary Dialer that has that function hard-coded into it. Without using a custom ROM, there is no way around it.

I know this because I have experience with this on Samsung devices (they also have a bar near the bottom that allows to Reject with Text), and having heavy proficiency with Android, outside of somehow recompiling the Dialer apk and using your knowledge of Java to find the entry, remove it, and recompile, there is unfortunately nothing you can do.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to `Phone > Call Settings` (Xperia Z3 go to `Settings > Call > Reject call with message`). There you'll see an option to "Reject Call with Message". Go there and you will see some template messages. Just delete all the messages one by one and that's it. Your problem is solved.

Comment: Hacky. But it works ;)